# I keep getting errors when trying to add a foreign key, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have an `episode` table with `episodeID` (PK), `airdate`, and `title`

I have a `show` table with `showID` (PK) which is VARCHAR(5)

I am using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE episode
ADD FOREIGN KEY (showID)
REFERENCES show(showID);
```

and I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show(showID)' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a foreign key constraint, so I recommend naming it.

However, your problem is that `show` is a reserved word:

```
ALTER TABLE episode ADD CONSTRAINT fk_episode_showid
     FOREIGN KEY (showID) REFERENCES `show`(showID);
```

I usually name tables in the plural (`shows` rather than `show`).  This both captures that they contain multiple rows.  And, it also makes them much less likely to conflict with reserved words.

Comment: Thank you for answering -- I removed my existing tables, change show to 'shows', and things went smoothly. I must ask, what is the ADD CONSTRAINT doing? I simply used ADD FOREIGN KEY etc. and then used those in PRIMARY KEY...did I do them all wrong? How can I verify, after the fact, that the foreign keys went through?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis . . . It is not wrong to add constraints without names.  However, I like to be explicit and give constraints names that make sense.